# How to redraw a customized view in onResume?

Tags: android, imageview, onresume, onmeasure

I have made a customized imageview with some editing for length and height size in onMeasure() in the view class. I have set this content in **onCreate** method of my Main Activity, but such changes didn't apply to my imageview.
Is there any solution that I can redraw my imageview in **onResume** method? Thus all my changes in onMeasure() in view class will apply.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks a lot !

Comment: If your Customized View extending ImageView? Call imageView.invalidate() in OnResume().
OR make global variable and call onMessure() in OnResume

Comment: @NaveenKumarM Could you please see my new question? I found this invalidate method doesn't figure out the problem. Thank you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711290/how-to-control-size-of-customized-imageview

Answer (score 0):

> Each class which is derived from the View class has the **invalidate()**
>   and the postInvalidate() method. If invalidate() gets called it tells
>   the system that the current view has changed and it should be redrawn
>   as soon as possible.

You can do the following on your onResume() method :

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    imageView.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Could you please see my new question? I found this invalidate method doesn't figure out the problem. Thank you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711290/how-to-control-size-of-customized-imageview